# VSTS list user's participation in projects

Tags: admin, azure-devops

I'm the administrator of my company's VSTS account. From time to time, I need to map users and projects, i.e., to list the projects that a particular user is member of. In vain, I have looked in many of VSTS' nooks and crannies and searched the online documentation. I'm grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you solve the issue with our solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to leverage the [VSTS REST APIs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview), you could:

- retrieve the [list of Team Projects](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects);
- iterating on all Team Projects, using the [Team REST APIs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/teams):

  - [Get List of Team](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/teams#get-a-list-of-teams);
  - [Get List of Member's of the Team](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/teams#get-a-teams-members);

Comment: Thanks, Luca! That's a passable route, if a bit winding =8-)

Answer (score 0):

The other way is that you can achieve that through client SDK.

There is simple sample to obtain teams for specific user that you can refer to:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("[collection url]"));

            collection.EnsureAuthenticated();

           var structureService= collection.GetService<ICommonStructureService>();
            var teamprojects = structureService.ListAllProjects();
            TfsTeamService teamService = collection.GetService<TfsTeamService>();
            UserInfo user = new UserInfo();
            foreach (var tp in teamprojects)
            {

                var teamList = teamService.QueryTeams(tp.Uri);
                foreach(var t in teamList)
                {
                    var userIdentity = t.GetMembers(collection, MembershipQuery.Expanded).Where(ti=>ti.UniqueName.Equals("[user accunt, e.g. domain\\test]",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if(userIdentity!=null)
                    {
                        user.Teams.Add(t.Name);
                        user.Alias = userIdentity.UniqueName;
                        user.DisplayName = userIdentity.DisplayName;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(user);
            Console.Read();
```